# Getting Django API data with Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm starting a project working with ember.js with Django Rest Framework for my REST Server.

I'm using an [adapter](http://dustinfarris.com/ember-django-adapter/) on the ember side to get the data into the right format that Ember needs. I'm at the point where I'm making a request to my server, and getting a 200 with data returning, however Ember is throwing an error `Error while processing route: index Assertion Failed: The response from a findAll must be an Array, not undefined`.

There are quite a few posts about this error, but I haven't been able to find any that are relevant to my problem, it seems to be a sort of blanket error that can be caused by many things?

I'm at a loss because my server is receiving the request and returning data in the format that I would expect from the server. I'm not sure how to tell if the error is within my Ember app or if my data is not being transformed correctly by the adapter.

```
// routers/index.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('user');
  }
});

// config/environment.js
APP: {
  API_NAMESPACE: 'v1',
  ENV.APP.API_HOST = 'http://localhost:8000',
},
```

Just having this code in my router is how I get the error. I feel like this is a very simple problem, but can't seem to get past it. I've tried moving that code into different parts such as the controller, just to see that I can fetch data. Hopefully someone has a suggestion, thanks. Let me know anything else I can post to help.

**EDIT: Going through the source it appears there is a problem in the serializer:**

```
extractArray: function(store, type, payload) {
    // Convert payload to json format expected by the RESTSerializer.
    // This function is being overridden instead of normalizePayload()
    // because `results` will only be in lists.
    console.log(type);
    var convertedPayload = {};
    if (payload.results) {
      convertedPayload[type.modelName] = payload.results;
    } else {
      convertedPayload[type.modelName] = payload;
    }
    return this._super(store, type, convertedPayload);
  },
```

The `type.modelName` is undefined. When I look at the type object, it's just a blank Class(). When i log `type.toString()` I get `joe2go@model:user:`

Could it be something related to my model? Everything seems pretty standard to me.

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  username: DS.attr('string'),
  firstName: DS.attr('string'),
  lastName: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Comment: The error is that the data is not formatted correctly in the response, and so where the adapter and ember-data expect there to be data there is nothing there.

Comment: If you post what version of ember-data you are using, as well as what your API response looks like for that end point, I can point you in the right direction.

Comment: I'm not sure the adapter you are using has been maintained well at all, you may need to roll your own ( I have a few times for django in the past).  If you need more extensive help ping me in #needhelp on the ember community slack.

Comment: @runspired Thx! I'm using 0.5.6 and the response from the server is the default response from DRF `[{'key':'value', 'key':'value'}]`. I have another project that has the adapter on the Django side and that works for that project, but was hoping to have the adapter on the ember side for this one.

Comment: What payload does the backend respond with?

Comment: @lolmaus-AndreyMikhaylov `[{'key':'value', 'key':'value'}]` I would expect the adapter to turn it into JSON-API/Ember format, but seems it might not be doing that.

Comment: Do you use both an adapter and a serializer from the django-ember addon?

Comment: yeah, using both the adapter and serializers from the addon

Comment: FYI, if you are using ember-data 1.13.7 or higher, you'll want to upgrade to the latest release of ember-django-adapter (v1.0.0)

Answer (score 0):

There is apparently a bug in the package.

```
extractArray: function(store, type, payload) {
 // Convert payload to json format expected by the RESTSerializer.
    // This function is being overridden instead of normalizePayload()
    // because `results` will only be in lists.

    var convertedPayload = {};
    if (payload.results) {
      convertedPayload[type.modelName] = payload.results;
    } else {
      convertedPayload[type.modelName] = payload;
    }
    return this._super(store, type, convertedPayload);
  },
```

Inside the serializer it refers to `type.modelName`, but that should be `type.typeKey`